# Share two instances between other classes

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have 4 coffeescript classes as the following:

```
class Main
  constructor: (element) ->
    @element = $(element)
    @one = new One()
    @two = new Two(@one)
    @dummy = new Dummy(@one, @two)

class One
  constructor: (class_two_instance) ->
    # do something

class Two
  constructor: (class_one_instance) ->
    # do something

class Dummy
  constructor: (class_one_instance, class_two_instance)
    # do something
jQuery ->
  new Main($("#main"))
```

I need the class `One` and the class `Two` to be shared between all other (actual or future) classes.

What I started to do is to pass them as parameters, as you can see in the `Main` class

```
@dummy = new Dummy(@one, @two)
```

But for the class `One` I need only to pass `@two`. The same thing for the class `Two` I need only to pass `@one`

Unfortunately it seems not possible to do that at the same time as you can see (I can't pass `@two` as parameter for `new One()` ):

```
@one = new One()
@two = new Two(@one)
```

Is there a way to solve that ?

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a "class" at all for them. Just objects.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what do you mean by that ?

Comment: It sounds like One and Two should just be objects, not classes, if you only ever one want of them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think I need them as classes because they contain a lot of logic and they have a lot of attributes which should be shared and modified by other classes

Comment: That's fine. It doesn't mean they need to be classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me as though `one` and `two` shouldn't be classes at all, just single objects:

```
one = {
  data: "I'm one",
  method: () ->
    # do something
    # if needed, you can use two here
}
two = {
  data: "I'm two",
  method: () ->
    # do something else
    # if needed, you can use one here
}
class Main
  constructor: (element) ->
    @element = $(element)
    @dummy = new Dummy()
    # if needed, you can use one and two here

class Dummy
  constructor: () ->
    # do something
    # if needed, you can use one and two here

jQuery ->
  new Main($("#main"))
```

Comment: I end up by changing the way my code is written but your answer is totally correct.. so I accept it. thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them as a prototype object.

`Dummy.prototype = Object.create(Two.prototype);`

then you can do the same thing with class Two and set it's prototype to one.

`Two.prototype = Object.create(One.prototype);`

Now Dummy instances will have access to all functions and properties that have been declared on prototype of Class One and Class Two.

As you can see for this pattern to work you need to define all *public* methods and properties on prototype in One and Two.